# Is it possible to reuse ansible tasks with some parameters override?

Tags: ansible

I want to create playbook to download only any package installed by ansible.

There is a lot of `yum state=installed` tasks in my ansible roles. Is there a way to include that roles without `state=installed`, but with `download_only` and `download_dir` instead?

ansible 2.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It is not possible. Use variables. For example

```
- yum:
    state: "{{ my_role1_yum_state|default(omit) }}"
    download_only: "{{ my_role1_yum_download_only|default(omit) }}"
    download_dir: "{{ my_role1_yum_download_dir|default(omit) }}"
    ...
```